# Div class not working after append

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have this html:

```
<div id="something" class="draggable">Hello World!</div>
```

When I press a button I invoke this code:

```
function addDiv(fatherDiv){
        $("#"+fatherDiv).append("<div id='randomId' class='draggable' style='position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 250px; width: 120px; height: 20px;'>Text of Div</div>");
    }
```

The problem is that the Div is created perfectly BUT the class doesn't work (draggable) when appending the Div, making it the only non draggable element.

How can I do so that the appended Div can become a draggable element just like the other divs?

Comment: `id`s must be unique. Don't add copies of the same div with the same id.

Comment: I'm guessing what you really intended to ask was ; Why does'nt a javascript function I initiated on a set of elements, work on dynamic elements as well.

Comment: you probably need to initialize draggable on the newly created element. Never used it so I am not 100% but it is logically sound to assume this

Comment: I know, that why I put in id='randomId'. :) Still that doesn't solve my question.. :(

Comment: That's why I added a comment and not an answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `.draggable()` on the newly created element, otherwise it is not bound. You can add that in your `addDiv` function by chaining it at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, how do I bind .draggable() if it is a class, not a method.

Comment: it's also in @joeframbach 's answer, but in short :  `$("#"+fatherDiv).append("....").draggable();`

Comment: You append the method on the end of your current jquery string

Comment: No, my answer is slightly different: `$("#"+fatherDiv).append($("....").draggable());`

Answer (score 1):

```
function addDiv(fatherDiv){
    $("#"+fatherDiv).append($("<div class='draggable' style='position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 250px; width: 120px; height: 20px;'>Text of Div</div>").draggable());
}
```

Comment: This is working 50% good now, the only problem is that now it is dragging is for the father div, not the created div. Is there any way to bind these two together without affecting the father div?

Comment: My guess is: $("#"+randomDiv).draggable(); ?

Comment: Yup, that worked! Thank you very much everyone! Great Help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with:

```
function addDiv(fatherDiv){
     $("#"+fatherDiv).append("<div id='randomId' class='draggable' style='position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 250px; width: 120px; height: 20px;'>Text of Div</div>");
     $("#"+fatherDiv).enhanceWithin();
}
```